# View returns System Object

Tags: navigation, prism, regions

In Prism 5, Unity, in a mvvm app, with the following navigate request, I get the System.Object instead of the view.

```
 RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainMenuRegion,
 new Uri("../../AdminModule/Views/MainMenuView", UriKind.Relative))
```

The navigation request is in a Login module and the target view is in another module that is loaded 'on demand' in bootstrapper.  The initialization class for the AdminModule just contains a simple Initialize().
The MainMenuView and MainMenuViewModel are basic.  I have tested them and they work o.k. T

I am trying to keep it simple at this point, and let the navigate request create the MainMenuView and do any necessary registrations so that I know which instance of the view is being targeted.

I added the following code to the LoginViewModel, and I end up with two instances of the AdminModule.Views.MainMenuView in my list of views for the MainMenuRegion, one being a type object, and the other being a type AdminModule.Views.MainMenuView.  The only time the AdminModule.Views.MainMenuView constructor is called is upon the container.resolve statement.

```
container.RegisterType<MainMenuView, MainMenuView>("MainMenuView"); 

   view = container.Resolve<MainMenuView>();

   RegionManager.Regions[(RegionNames.MainMenuRegion)].Add(view, "MainMenuView");
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the view is not registered. All views are registered as type object against a string key. If the key is not found, Unity will return just a new object. So in your module (IModule implementation) make sure you are registering your views with the container.

e.g.

```
container.RegisterType<Object, MainMenuView>("MainMenuView");
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think this error is a combination of things.  I will just put this post on hold for now until I re-check the xaml in my view.